# Php function with return statement

Tags: php, function

Can somebody explain me this code?  I don't understand why it outputs 21.

```
<?php
function math($t){

if($t==0)
return 0;    
return $t+ math($t-1);

}   
 echo math(6);

       ?>
```

It will echo 21. I have no idea how it got this result.

Comment: The maths is 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

Comment: Do you understand recursion?

Answer (score 4):

The function is recursive, it calls itself until it gets to `0`, then adds all the previously returned values (6,5,4,3,2,1).

```
function math($t){
    if($t==0)
        return 0;    
    return $t+ math($t-1);

}   
echo math(6);
```

So on loop one it gets `6` then `6-1` = `5` so `math` gets called again with  `5` this time and so on. Take a look at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e228f3b696c5058efee03fa978a09179c1f2ffbb.